# Comparing two sheets and color coding rows

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is compare the rows in sheet 1 to those in sheet 2.  The below images are just an example of what I am trying to do.  In sheet1, the first row compared to sheet2 (columns A and C are needed to compare but not column B) is correct and the rows are blue, in the second row Column C is incorrect and shows as red which is also what I need, but the third row (column A) does not exist in sheet2 and what I need is it to either not have a color assigned to it or a different color then red if this makes sense.  The code is in VBA and listed below the images.

Basically what I need is to not have row 3 colored red as column A(899) does not exist in column A in sheet2.  Hopefully this clarifies this.s

Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckRows()
   Dim cl As Range
   Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim Vlu As String
   Dim rc As Integer
   Dim RowCount As Integer
   Dim RowCount2 As Integer
  
 
 
   Set Ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set Ws2 = Sheets("sheet2")
   RowCount = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   RowCount2 = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For rc = 1 To RowCount2
         Vlu = Ws2.Range("A" & rc) & Ws2.Range("C" & rc)
         .Item(Vlu) = Empty
      Next rc
  
      For rc = 1 To RowCount
         Vlu = Ws1.Range("A" & rc) & Ws1.Range("C" & rc)
         If .exists(Vlu) Then
            Cells(rc, 1).EntireRow.Interior.color = vbGreen
            Else
            Cells(rc, 1).EntireRow.Interior.color = vbRed
         End If
      Next rc
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks to me like it can be done without VBA using conditional formatting. Am I right in thinking that the values in column A will be unique on that worksheet?

Comment: Needs to be VBA as there is more to the workbook then I have shown here. and yes column A in sheet1 will be unique

Comment: Not an answer but you should declare variables that store row number as a `Long` instead of `Integer` as the maximum number of rows is bigger than what `Integer` can hold and thus can cause overflow error. (So `rc`, `RowCount` and `RowCount2` should declared as `Long`)

Comment: You can apply CF using VBA.

Comment: Do you need coloring of only the first three columns, like you show us in your picture, or all the row?

Comment: It would be nice to just have the columns in use to be colored instead of the entire row but not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It should be very fast, using arrays for and union ranges to color the interior at once, at the end:

```
Sub CheckRowsBis()
   Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim RowCount As Long, RowCount2 As Long, arr1, arr2
   Dim rngGr As Range, rngRed As Range, i As Long, j As Long
  
   Set Ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set Ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   RowCount = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   RowCount2 = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Ws1.Range("A1:C" & RowCount).Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear the interior color of the whole range
   arr1 = Ws1.Range("A1:C" & RowCount).Value       'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   arr2 = Ws2.Range("A1:C" & RowCount2).Value     'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(j, 1) Then
                If arr1(i, 3) = arr2(j, 3) Then
                    If rngGr Is Nothing Then
                       Set rngGr = Ws1.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
                    Else
                      Set rngGr = Union(rngGr, Ws1.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i))
                    End If
                 Else
                    If rngRed Is Nothing Then
                       Set rngRed = Ws1.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i)
                    Else
                      Set rngRed = Union(rngRed, Ws1.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
   Next
   If Not rngGr Is Nothing Then rngGr.Interior.Color = vbGreen
   If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then rngRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

'Coloring each three cells range takes time...

Comment: In the code above it colors column A all red in all three rows, even though one of the rows is a correct match for sheet2.

Comment: Time is not important for the task

Comment: @scubadivingfool The first version used to color only A:C cells, then I tried adapting it to color entire row and forgot to adapt the last two. I did it now. Then, it should not be possible to behave as you said... If not something confidential, can you share your testing workbook?

Comment: Here is the link and I have made the sheets looks like what I need them to be.  Biggest thing is that if Column A in sheet1 does not exist in sheet2, then I need the color not to change.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qXnlH8lEyInddvyTmrlySJ-fwajGOMKV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @scubadivingfool What do you mean by "Column A in sheet1 does not exist in sheet2"? The above code checks if column A:A in both sheets has the same number of rows. So, if it does not exist, it will send a message saying that and stop the code. I will download your file and make some test and then will reply

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "if the cell in column A doesn't exist.  As you can tell by row 3, cloumn A in sheet 1, it does not exist in sheet2.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @scubadivingfool I am afraid I did not understand what you want... So, you do not want comparing each row of the two sheets? Do you want searching in all sheet2 A\C values and make the row green if it find a match and red if not?

Comment: OK, let me try this.  If 831/G101 exists in sheet2 and the price in column C are both correct then the cell would be true and formatted into blue.  if 831/G101 exists in sheet2 but column C is not the same in sheet 1 then format the cells in red.  if 831/G101 does not exit in column A in sheet 2 then do not format in any color.

Comment: @scubadivingfool Please, test the updated code. Now it checks **each pair A-C** from first sheet in all such combinations of the second one. If it finds a match, the interior is colored in Green. If not, it is colored in Red... If you want coloring only the range A:C, I may easily adapt the code...

Comment: On cell 3, column A of sheet1, 899 does not exist in sheet2, thus I do not need this to change to red.

Comment: @scubadivingfool Then, **WHEN do you want a range to be colored in red**? In which circumstances? I thought that the situation must be dynamic. I mean, if you run it second time, maybe something has been changed. So, if it was green in the previous run and something changed, is should become red... So, please answer my first question!

Comment: When I need the row to be in red is when, say 899 in sheet1 and row A is in sheet2 but the 899 in sheet1 row C has and number that does not equal what the Row C in sheet2 states.  Won't be able to answer for a while as I will be on the road.

Comment: @scubadivingfool Please, test the updated code. Now it colors in red if a match of `A & i` from sheet1 could be found in A:A column of the sheet2 and green if values in C:C, on the same row are also matching.

Comment: @scubadivingfool Your processed workbook to be downloaded from [here](https://easyupload.io/25i012).

Comment: @scubadivingfool Still the above code did not do what you need?

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for your help